# Save and Open file Dialogs

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, event-handling

I AM USING C++. I am currently designing a program with windows forms. I am having a problem writing event handlers. especially the click event handler for save and open file. I have searched the net and can find no decent explanation on how to write these event handlers. So i am asking for a well defined definition.

Please do not send me to Microsoft as they do not provide a sample of completed event handlers only partially.

Comment: @InfinityCounter: since the question was closed (it's just SO, it's not your fault) I've posted **[answer code](http://pastie.org/6466699)** at pastie.org. See the long comment line showing how to add a click event handler, and the code at bottom for running a file open dialog.

Comment: @InfinityCounter, Since you made it so clear that you're using C++, I get the feeling that you are actually using C++/CLI, which is quite different.

Comment: @chris: the OP is *necessarily* using some Microsoft language extension, not pure standard C++. that's why the question is tagged visual c++. and also winforms.

Comment: I thank you all for your comments negative and positive. And even thought the question was closed  I got something out of it, thank you for your time, especially @Alf you seem to have great patience and understanding, the source code has been very useful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's not obvious at a glance that Visual Studio 2012 does support C++/CLI Winform applications, even though the OP certainly knows this, for other readers, here's how I created one just to answer this question:

1. In Visual Studio 2012, in the New Project dialog I selected [Visual C++ > CLR > CLR Empty Project].
2. In the new project I added an ordinary C++ `main` function and a Windows Form.
3. In the linker settings I changed it from console subsystem to GUI subsystem (and due to the non-standard behavior of Microsoft's linker, adjusted the entry point to `mainCRTStartup`).

That said, below is shown the generated Winform header, with just the event handler code, which fires up an Open File dialog, added manually.

- The long comment line `------` shows how to connect up an event handler.
- The code at the bottom shows both how to code up an event handler, and how to run the open file dialog.

```
#pragma once

namespace CppWindowsFormsApplication {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MainWindow
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MainWindow : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MainWindow(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MainWindow()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(149, 208);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->button1->Text = L"&Open file";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

            // ---------------------------------------------------- !Adds event handler -------------------
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MainWindow::button1_Click);
            // 
            // MainWindow
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"MainWindow";
            this->Text = L"MainWindow";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);

        }
#pragma endregion
    private:
        System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog^ sfd = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
            sfd->Filter = "Text Files|*.txt|All Files|*.*";
            if( sfd->ShowDialog() != System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
            {
                return;
            }
            //MessageBox::Show( sfd->FileName );
            MessageBox::Show( "OK" );
        }
    };
}
```

I didn't fix the indenting etc., since I didn't have the time; nearly all of this code was generated by Visual Studio 2012's RAD (*Rabid Application Development*) feature.

---

Related to this question’s history, now removed:

I didn't really have the time to answer this question. I would much rather have let someone else answer it (and reap some reputation from it). It is such a simple question that I’m sure if it wasn’t closed so fast, any number of readers, with more time than I had, would have answered it.

But answering it, with code posted elsewhere, and forsaking some other matters, was the only way I saw to have it reopened.

I sincerely ask every reader to **please don't vote to close what you don’t understand**.

Only vote to close a question when you thoroughly understand the subject matter and can *prove* to yourself and others that the community is better off with the question closed.

Failure to understand a question does *not* necessarily mean that the question is ungood.

Comment: I understand that you want to express your opinion about closing on SO incorrectly but users who arrive here trying to get assistance with similar issues are not helped by that last part. It would require those who explicitly closed _this_ question to check back here for your answer and also read that addition. IMHO it's the wrong place for that information.

Comment: @Default: no, i don't "want to express [my] opinion", that's misleading. i simply do what's best for the community. your statement about readers ending up here to get an answer is literally correct but rather irrelevant and misleading. your statement about requirement for any effect, is just wrong. but it is "formally" the wrong place for this information. instead by effective SO rules it should be placed where it reaches no-one of the relevant audience, namely over at meta.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's misleading. An answer for me should contain an answer and information related to an answer. A statement, even though it might be neccessary to highlight, of "please don't close questions if you do not understand why" (where "questions" can relate to **any** question, not just this one), to me, is not answering the question at hand. This is why I feel it is redundant.